# Accessing token authenticated user in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, token

I currently have an API set up with token authentication. I have a parent class `ApiController` that my other API controllers inherit from that contains the following:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  protected 
    def authenticate
      authenticate_token || render_unauthorized
    end

    def authenticate_token
      authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        User.find_by(auth_token: token)
      end
    end

    def render_unauthorized
      self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Token realm="Users"'
      render json: 'Bad credentials', status: 401
    end
end
```

In my API controllers I just set `before_action :authenticate` to make sure it's a valid request from a user with an `auth_token`.

I sometimes need the user that issued the request, for example, when following a user I need to make the user that made the request follow another user, looking at what I have how can I set it up so in my controller I can access the user that made the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an instance variable that will be accessible by your Controller in your `authenticate_token` method.  As such

```
 @current_user = User.find_by(auth_token: token)
```

Then, for example, the Controller::Action you define to "follow" a user can use `@current_user`.

```
 def follow()     
   @current_user.follow (another_user)
 end
```